# Programme Returns NULL Object

Tags: php, design-patterns

I want to demonstrate Factory Design Pattern using PHP Code snippet. So i develop this code by my self. But it gives me NULL object .Please help me to resolve this .

```
<?php
class Book{
    private $bookName;
    private $bookAuthor;
    const lineBreak = "<br/>";

    public function __construct($bookName,$bookAuthor)
    {
        $this->bookName = $bookName;
        $this->bookAuthor = $bookAuthor;
    }

    public function getBookInfo(){
        return $this->bookName .'-'.$this->bookAuthor .self::lineBreak;
    }

    }

class BookFactory{

    public function __construct($bookName,$bookAuthor)
    {

        $book = new Book($bookName,$bookAuthor);

        return  $book->getBookInfo();

    }

}

$bookOne = new BookFactory("Digital World","David Perera");

$bookTwo = new BookFactory("Harry Porter","James bond");

var_dump($bookOne);
```

Comment: The return value of the constructor is ignored. `new BookFactory()` always returns a `BookFactory` object.

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks . Could you please elaborate it ? how could i over come this problem?

Comment: I tried your code. I don't get `NULL`. I get `object(BookFactory)#1 (0) {
}`

Comment: @Barmar -Yes you are correct . Now  I modified my code. still same result

Comment: You'll still get the same result. Like I said, it doesn't matter what you return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement the factory pattern in the constructor. `new Classname` always returns an object of that class, not what the constructor returns.

Instead, you should use a static method to create the object.

```
class BookFactory{

    public static function createBook($bookName,$bookAuthor)
    {
        return new Book($bookName,$bookAuthor);
    }
}

$bookOne = BookFactory::createBook("Digital World","David Perera");
$bookTwo = BookFactory::createBook("Harry Porter","James bond");

var_dump($bookOne);
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar . i have one question. i m new bee for php. why we cannot access class method like this . new Book($bookName,$bookAuthor)->getBookInfo() , why we need always create object reference ?

Comment: Because of default operator precedence, you need parentheses around the `new` expression: `echo (new Book("Harry Porter","James bond"))->getBookInfo();`